# Advice needed for split core clamp-on power monitoring circuit

Tags: mains, current-transformer

I am trying to get started with the analog end of a circuit to measure power with a split core transformer.  I'm wondering if I can get any pointers about what kind of circuits I might need right after the transformer to make the signal readable by a microcontroller, as well as any links to schematics on the web, which seem strangely minimal.  This is for a 120V AC circuit at a max rating of 30A.

This would seem to point to using a transimpedance amplifier directly after the transformer.  Since it's only 60Hz, the amp wouldn't really need a whole lot of (any?) roll-off/frequency response shaping at all.  Then, it would be on to an ADC, which would have to sample the voltage from the amp (representing current), along with the line voltage, and be doing it fast enough to figure out the phase difference between the two and perform as close to a "true" RMS power calculation as possible (by integration I think?).

Is this the way "it's done" typically?  Am I missing any critical components/steps?

Thanks!
-Dewey

Comment: can you provide any info about the transformer ? (website, model, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said anything about the loads to be measured or the accuracy required so I'll answer generally.

Picking up on what you said about phase difference: measuring power is not this simple as you cannot assume a sinusoidal load current. Any switching power supply will switch at least in the 10s of kHz with important harmonics more than 10x higher. In other words, it isn't "only 60Hz". You can sample with a CT optimized for low frequency, but your result may not be anything near what usually passes for "True RMS".

The phase difference between the voltage and current is only useful for simple power factor calculations with a sinusoidal load current, typically found in an inductive load like a large motor. With any non-sinusoidal load current it doesn't matter so much. Power meters sometimes report it separately from power factor, calling it "displacement power factor" or somesuch.  From a noisy switching load you can see a "displacement power factor" of 0.95 or so but a real power factor of 0.50. That shows you how misleading it is by itself.

What you're proposing can give perfectly usable results, it all depends on your specification.